# Fix Security Issue : S3 permissions granted to other AWS accounts in bucket policies should be restricted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-appflow

I have a [security issue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/securityhub/S3.6/remediation) raised by Trusted Advisor.

**S3 permissions granted to other AWS accounts in bucket policies should be restricted
**

This checks if the S3 bucket policy allows sensitive bucket-level or object-level actions from a principal in another AWS account. The check fails if any of the following actions are allowed in the S3 bucket policy for a principal in another AWS account: s3:DeleteBucketPolicy, s3:PutBucketAcl, s3:PutBucketPolicy, s3:PutObjectAcl, and s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration.

I have an S3 bucket that is failing to comply this check. It has a bunch of statements in its bucket policy. The one that is causing the security check to fail is the following :

```
{
    "Sid": "AllowAppFlowDestinationActions",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "appflow.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::qa-abhra",
        "arn:aws:s3:::qa-abhra/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:SourceAccount": "account_number"
        },
        "ArnLike": {
            "aws:SourceArn": [
                "arn:aws:appflow:us-east-1:account_number:flow/contacts",
                "arn:aws:appflow:us-east-1:account_number:flow/account"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the Service associated in the statement is not tied to an AWS account. But I have been able to mention the condition and ArnLike in the statement above as suggested in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/s3-policies-management.html)
Why am I still getting the same security alert from Trusted Advisor?
What can I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the alert is caused by `s3:PutObjectAcl`.

Are you sure that you need to provide this permission? It can be used to "set the access control list (ACL) permissions for a new or existing object in an S3 bucket".

For example, it **could be used to change a 'private' object into a 'public' object**.

It could be safer *not* to provide this permission. The external service can set the ACL when it *creates* an object. There should be no need for it to change the ACL *after* the object has been created.

However, if you feel that the permissions are fine as-is, you can tell Trusted Advisor to **exclude** that item.

Comment: I can confirm that removing the s3:PutObjectAcl has fixed the alert to go off. I just have a  follow-up question. It would be great if you help me understand if with the above statement I was able to tie the Service to a particular AWS account? It seems the alert went off because I removed the action mentioned and the bucket policy still has allowed access of Principals in another AWS accounts.

Comment: No idea! I was just basing my recommendation on the description you provided in the question.